# Ember set subtraction with PromiseArrays

Tags: ember.js, set

I have two `PromiseArray` objects, from within a controller, e.g. `this.get('content.skills')` and `this.get('allSkills')`.

I'd like to do what is essentially set subtraction. For example:

```
[1, 2, 3] - [2, 3] // => [1]
```

Is there a straightforward to do this? There's [an alias for doing intersections](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_intersect). My guess is that it will use `rejectBy` somehow, but I'm not quite sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_removeObjects with the Promise's content as long as they are fulfilled.

`P1.removeObjects(P2.toArray());`